# Unable to find a way to solve this logarithmic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\log _{ 5 }{ (3^{ 2x }+6) } =\log _{ 5 }{ 3^{ x } } +1$$

Steps I took:

I realize that this actually means $5^{ \log _{ 5 }{ 3^{ x } } +1 }=3^{ 2x }+6$; however, I can't seem to find a clear cut path to the solution from here. I would prefer a hint that will help me arrive at the solution rather than the actual answer.

Comment: Remember that $5^{a+b} = 5^a\times5^b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just notice that
$$\log _{ 5 }{ (3^{ 2x }+6) } =\log _{ 5 }{ 3^{ x } } +1\iff \log_5{(3^{2x}+6)}-\log_5 3^x = 1 \iff \frac{3^{2x}+6}{3^x}=5^1$$

Then, by putting $t=3^x$ you can solve last equation by solving $$t^2+6=5t$$ and after that, solving for $x$.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, we have $$\log_5(3^{2x}+6)=\log_53^{x}+1$$
$$\log_5(3^{2x}+6)=\log_53^{x}+\log_55$$
$$\log_5(3^{2x}+6)=\log_5(5\cdot 3^{x})$$$$3^{2x}+6=5\cdot 3^x$$
$$(3^x)^2-5(3^x)+6=0$$ $$(3^x-2)(3^x-3)=0$$
$$\implies 3^x-2=0\implies x\log 3=\log 2$$ $$\color{red}{x=\frac{\log 2}{\log 3}=\log_32}$$
$$\implies 3^x-3=0\implies x\log 3=\log 3$$ $$\color{red}{x=1}$$